# Node.js Error: Can't set headers after they are sent, appears sometimes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a HTML form with a post method, and a post route

```
    app.post('/',
        c_emailController.create,
        c_bookingController.create
    );
```

When i press submit, i need send a email to me and to the client [emailController], and save the data in my bookings collection [bookingController], but sometimes, when i press the submit, this error appears:

```
Can't set headers after they are sent
```

The most strange part is: is not everytime, sometimes happens, sometimes don't. Can you check out my controllers code and see if there is a problem?

I believe this is a problem with the next();.

JS FIDDLE -> http://jsfiddle.net/a6s7npcg/

OBS: The code is working when the error not occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're calling the `next` callback twice by calling the `sendEmail` function twice.

To avoid that you can use [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, with the help of which you will send the emails in [parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) and and call `next` only after both emails are sent.

```
var async = require('async');

async.parallel({
   alertEmail: function(callback) {
       var alertEmailOptions = {
        to: "myemail@com",
        from: "myemail@com",
        subject: "[alert]",
        html: "some html",
       };
       sendgrid.send(alertEmailOptions , callback);
   }, 
   confirmEmail: function(callback) {
        var confirmationEventOptions = {
        to: req.body.email,
        from: "reserva@pubcrawlsp.com",
        subject: "Reserva -  "
        html: "SOME HTML",
        };
        sendgrid.send(confirmationEventOptions, callback);
   }
}, function (err, results) {
   next();
});
```

Comment: this stop the error, but there is a problem here.. when i click in the submit, the code runs, them return to the / (perfect normal), but the page is loading all the time, without stop..

Comment: nevermind, i figure out the problem.. haha.. THANKS VERY MUCH @Vsevolod